# element slider start from 0 to bottom (negative) instead 0 to top in firefox

Tags: javascript, scroll

The element slider in all browsers starts from 0 up to top (ex: `0 to 500`) that's when the direction of page is `left to right`, and when the direction of page is `right to left` the slider starts from top to 0 (ex: `500 to 0`).
The `firefox` is the only browser which is different when the direction of page is `right to left` starts from 0 to bottom (ex: `0 to -500`) negative number.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
box.onscroll = function() {
  result.innerHTML = box.scrollLeft;
}
```

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
}
#box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
#childBox {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/school_symbols_seamless_pattern_311368.jpg') repeat-x;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="childBox"></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Also [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ukeewc1/).

**How to make the firefox to treats the element slider like all browsers ?**

Answer (score 0):

Now that's something I didn't know, cool. Even the MDN explicitly says that Firefox' is the [correct behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft). But if all the other browser behaves like that, there's no point in being different, especially for an old spec like `scrollLeft`.

Anyway, there *is* a way to make Firefox work like the other ones, and involves a (rather invasive, to be fair) trick. Firefox also supports the non-standard property [`scrollLeftMax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeftMax) which may come in handy, because it saves us to check the element's computed style: if an element is horizontally scrollable, but `scrollLeftMax` is zero, then it's right-to-left and needs to be adjusted:

```
if (!("scrollLeftMax" in Element.prototype)) return;

var scrollLeftDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "scrollLeft");

Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "scrollLeft", {
    get: function() {
        var diff = this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth;

        return scrollLeftDesc.get.call(this) + (this.scrollLeftMax ? 0 : diff);
    },
    set: function(v) {
        var diff = this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth;

        scrollLeftDesc.set.call(this, v - (this.scrollLeftMax ? 0 : diff));

        return v;
    }
});
```

The `scroll` method should be taken care of too if needed or for completeness:

```
var originalScroll = Element.prototype.scroll;

Element.prototype.scroll = function(x, y) {
    var diff = this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth;

    originalScroll(x - (this.scrollLeftMax ? 0 : diff), y);
};
```

The point is understanding when to apply it. I don't think there's a way to preemptively check this without adding a dummy element to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this way is long, and difficult.
I think this trouble is just a failure in firefox.

Comment: @LionKing My post has been more like a proof of concept more than anything, as I don't really recommend doing it: it's invasive, needs a lot of work and comes with a performance penalty. But it *does* answer your question, doesn't it?